# Expand Timeout while executing query on PSycopg2/Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am working on complex query that takes hours to execute.
I am using PSycopg2 to

By reading this [Post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/postgresql-set-ing-from-psql-arguments) . I added this statement :

```
 import os.environ
    ['PGOPTIONS'] = '-c statement_timeout=1000000'
```

Now, I am getting an error every-time, I execute this query :

```
import psycopg2
>>> cnn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test options='-c statement_timeout=1000'")
>>> cur = cnn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("select pg_sleep(200000)")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.extensions.QueryCanceledError: canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

My question: 
How can I force the application to take a long time to process the query ?

Comment: What's your *question*? The obvious thing to do seems to be "do not set a timeout if you do not want one".

Comment: Craig Ringer: I wanted to force the application to take a long time to process the query ?

Answer (score 8):

If you want your app to take a long time to process a query, you must remove the statement timeout that is forcing it to terminate early.

Remove:

```
 import os.environ
    ['PGOPTIONS'] = '-c statement_timeout=1000000'
```

and in your connection string remove the `options` entry.

```
>>> cnn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test")
```

Now, if you instead wish to retain a timeout in general, but override it for just this query, then before the query, explicitly `SET statement_timeout` to override the default you set:

```
cur.execute("SET statement_timeout = 0")
cur.execute("select pg_sleep(200000)")
```

... and if that's the case *why didn't you say so*?